# Correct spacing between roses

Tags: growth, roses, climate, spacing

I have 3 hybrid tea's and a grandiflora in pots that i wish to transplant to the ground this spring but im unsure about the right spacing distance between each them. I've been reading about it on the internet and opinions vary from 2ft, 2 and a half to 3ft. I dont want to plant my roses too close to invite issues relating to disease nor too far to have large gaps in between. I'll be planting them in the South-eastern side where they'll get plenty of sunlight. We have a semi arid climate with summers that are hot and dry. What would be the ideal spacing under such conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Roses vary quite a bit in height and spread and growth habit - some are vigorous and get quite tall and wide, others are small in comparison. The spacing is dictated by the eventual spread or width of the rose concerned - if one of them gets, say, 3 feet in spread, and another makes five feet, then you will need to plant the first and the second will need to be five feet away. Hopefully you know the varietal names of the roses you have... if you don't, you'll need to play safe and space them about 5 feet apart to allow for good airflow around them. Not sure what you mean by 'grandiflora' rose - floribunda perhaps?

Comment: Grandifloras are hybrids of a floribunda and a hybrid tea. The best ones have the repeat blooming and cluster blooming habits of a floribunda with the flower shape of a HT. They tend to grow taller than anything except climbing roses, so don't crowd them!.

Comment: As well as the spread, don't forget that you need access to them to prune them. Maybe that's not a big deal if you only have three bushes, but for a larger bed you need to be able to work on the ones in the center without being scratched to death by thorns!

Comment: @alephzero-  couldn't find 'grandiflora' via Firefox, and never heard the expression before. But both HT and floribundas are repeat flowering  anyway,always have been... but grandiflora does suggest a taller, larger plant perhaps. Irritating though - deadheading is easier and 'cleaner' on HTs than floribundas, so grandiflora will fall into floribunda in terms of deadheading then...